# Changing the username should effect in all other pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using ionic4/angular4.the changes made to the username should reflect in all pages. here I am using ngModel to bind the data but I am unable to access the ngModel variable in other pages. Please help me with the proper code example.

```
 <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Profile Name" [readonly]="isReadOnly" [(ngModel)]="username" name="profile"
          #nameCtrl="ngModel" required minlength="3" pattern="^[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ ,.'-]+$" (focusout)="out_profile()" #name
          no-padding>
        </ion-input
```

Comment: You can only use ngModel in component the in which's template ngModel is used.
Are you saying on changing username in this component, you want it changed in other pages as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular Providers to achieve this.

I am referring the page where you input the username as **username.component.ts**

**`username.component.html`**

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Profile Name" [readonly]="isReadOnly" [value]="username" name="profile"
      #nameCtrl="ngModel" required minlength="3" pattern="^[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ ,.'-]+$" (focusout)="out_profile()" #name
      no-padding
(input)="usernameChange(name.value)"
>
</ion-input
```

**`username.component.ts`**

```
// this will be called everytime you enter something in input field
// you can use debounceTime( 1000 ) here to delay that.
usernameChange(username) {
    this.usernameService.usernameChangeSubject.next(username);
}
```

**`username.service.ts`**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsernameService {
    usernameChangeSubject : Subject<string> = new Subject();
    usernameChange$ : Observable<string> = this.usernameChangeSubject.asObservable();
}
```

**`some-other-page.component.ts`**

```
username : string;
constructor(usernameService : UsernameService) {
    this.usernameService.usernameChange$.subscribe(newUsername => {
        // you will have updated username here, use newUsername
        this.username = newUsername;
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you.what is suppose to be there in comment u have made in some-other-page.ts.

Comment: There you can have a local variable like, `username` and update it's value. I have updated the answer

Comment: ur method didn't work so I used localStorage API.it solved my problem by just 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

@yashpatelyk's answer is a good quality answer, and a best practice. However, it took me a long time to get my head around using the rxjs library, like it is being used in these example codes.

If you are looking for perhaps a simpler solution that is still a decent coding technique I would look into Ionic Events.

The best tutorial I have seen is on Alligator.io:

- [Using Events in Ionic to Pass Data & Messages Between Pages](https://alligator.io/ionic/events/)

Basically you can do what is being done in the other answer but basically, in one page/component/section of your site you can do this:

```
handleClick(){
  this.events1.publish('my-message', ' Hello from page1!');
}
```

And then in another, you can do this:

```
constructor(public events2: Events){
  this.events2.subscribe('my-message', (data) =>{
    console.log(data); //  Hello from page1!
  });
}
```

All you have to do is make sure you import the `Events` system and then inject it into your constructor, just like you would with any normal service.

Import like this:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Inject like this:

```
constructor(public events: Events){
}
```

Comment: This works too. But I prefer Observables over Events. I think it makes more sense.